# Python on OS X: ImportError: No module named fsevents

Tags: python, macos, import, fsevents

I know nothing about python, but I have a (used to be) working script someone else wrote, and in that script are the following two lines:

```
from fsevents import Observer
from fsevents import Stream
```

When I execute the python script from Terminal via this command:

```
python myScript.py
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myScript", line 23, in <module>
    from fsevents import Observer
ImportError: No module named fsevents
```

I'm now running 10.8.4 on a different machine from when the script used to work. Could I be missing some 3rd party installs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have not installed fsevents, you can download fsevents from here https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MacFSEvents

extract the repository and cd into and do python setup.py install.

Comment: Thank you! It installed fine.